# AfterViews method not called in fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-annotations

I am using `Android annotation` in `Fragment` class but `@AfterViews` annotated method is not getting called. Here is the code:

```
@EFragment(R.layout.fragment_onboarding_base)
public class AddEntityFragment extends Fragment {

@ViewById ViewPager onBoardingViewPager;

public static AddEntityFragment newInstance() {
    AddEntityFragment addEntityFragment = new AddEntityFragment();
    return addEntityFragment;
}

@AfterViews
void afterViewCreated(){
    onBoardingViewPager.setAdapter(new CustomOnBoardingPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager(), getContext()));
}
}
```

What I am doing wrong here? I checked my debug point it's not going inside to `afterViewCreated()` method. Any help would be appreciable.

Comment: why don't you use `onViewCreated`?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you are not using the generated class. You should do this instead:

```
AddEntityFragment fragment = AddEntityFragment_.builder().build();
// add the fragment in a transaction
```